# Display future single post 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error

I have a custom post type `kalender`, a template which displays all of the posts in this custom post type and a `single-kalender.php`. Everything works fine when the user is logged in but when logged out the single pages return a `404 error`.

I'm assuming I get the `404` because I'm trying to display future posts when not logged in. How would I go ahead and solve this issue?

**EDIT 1**

```
$labels = array(
  'name' => __('Events'),
  'singular_name' => __('Event'),
  'add_new' => __('Nieuw event'),
  'add_new_item' => __('Nieuw event'),
  'edit_item' => __('Event bewerken'),
  'new_item' => __('Nieuw event'),
  'view_item' => __('Bekijk event'),
  'search_items' => __('Doorzoek Events'),
  'not_found' =>  __('Niets gevonden'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('Niets gevonden in de prullenbak'),
  'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/events.png',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
  'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'kalender' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

**EDIT 2**

I've added some code in the `404.php` template which would detect if the page which is trying to load is in the custom post type `kalender`. This works:

```
<?php 
    global $wp_query;

    if ('kalender' == $wp_query->query_vars["post_type"]) {
        include 'single-kalender.php';
    }
    else{ ?>
        </div><!-- .menu-container -->
        <h1>Error 404</h1
<?php } ?>
```

Now I'm trying to query that specific single custom post type in the `single-kalender.php` template but I can't get it to work. The following query outputs no posts, even though the `found_posts` variable is 1 (works as expected) but the `posts` array remains empty unfortunately.

```
global $wp_query;
$name = $wp_query->query_vars["name"];

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where_from_today' );

$query = new WP_Query(array('post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ), 'post_type' => 'kalender', 'order' => 'ASC', 'name' => $name ));
```

When I use the generated query on my database it selects the single custom post type as expected, the generated query is the following:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'slug-of-the-post' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'kalender' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') AND post_date > '2013-04-11'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
```

If you want to check the whole `print_r($query)` see here: **http://pastebin.com/cSzmXDVb**

Comment: Please post the code used to create your CPT. Chances are you have set incorrect capabilities on it.

Comment: No I didn't seriously called it `CPT`, it was just an example. I'll post the code above.

Comment: Well default caps will be 'post', so as long as your anonymous users can read posts this should work. Do you have a caching plugin active?

Comment: No caching plugin active. I'm assuming anonymous users can't read the posts because they are scheduled to be posted in the future.

Comment: Okay I'm confused. Why do you want users to see posts that are not published until a future date? If you've built your CPT to use the publication date in a way other than the way it was intended, that was a mistake. You should create a custom field for your dates in your CPT, and leave the publication date alone.

Comment: I admit, it was a mistake, a big one. But it seemed like the easiest way to go. Currently I can get the `single-kalender.php` to load but I can't seem to query the single custom post. How would I query the single custom post when I have the `slug`?

Comment: You'd have to show your code for this.

Comment: Added the code to the main post.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to go to chat on this. If your single-kalendar.php works for posts that are not in the future, and works for future posts when you are logged in, then the code there is probably sound. The problem may be that you are trying to include it again in a 404 page. I don't know what data WP makes available to a 404. I would advise against taking this route. Just as messing with publication dates is a bad idea, so is messing with 404s.

Comment: Managed to get it to work yesterday with some real dirty code, which I will not post below because I wouldn't want others to use it.